# define a closure as method from class

Tags: php, closures

i'm trying to play with php5.3 and closure.

I see here (Listing 7. Closure inside an object : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-5.3new2/index.html) that it's possible to use $this in the callback function, but it's not. So I try to give $this as use variable :

```
$self = $this;
$foo = function() use($self) { //do something with $self }
```

So to use the same example :

```
class Dog
{
private $_name;
protected $_color;

public function __construct($name, $color)
{
     $this->_name = $name;
     $this->_color = $color;
}
public function greet($greeting)
{
     $self = $this;
     return function() use ($greeting, $self) {
         echo "$greeting, I am a {$self->_color} dog named {$self->_name}.";
     };
}
}

$dog = new Dog("Rover","red");
$dog->greet("Hello");

Output:
Hello, I am a red dog named Rover.
```

First of all this example does not print the string but return the function, but that's not my problem.

Secondly I can't access to private or protected, because the callback function is a global function and not in the context from the Dog object. Tha't my problem. It's the same as :

```
function greet($greeting, $object) {
    echo "$greeting, I am a {$self->_color} dog named {$self->_name}.";
}
```

And I want :

```
public function greet($greeting) {
    echo "$greeting, I am a {$self->_color} dog named {$self->_name}.";
}
```

Which is from Dog and not global.

Comment: No, I didn't understand what you want. If greet is a method, the visibility defauls to public, so your two last code blocks are equivalent.

Comment: That magic injection of `$this` in a clojure has been dropped before PHP 5.3 was released. Actually, it was postponed for an upcoming version of PHP. There will some something like `Closure::bindTo` that one can use to bind objects as contexts to lambdas.

Answer (score 9):

Well, the whole reason that you can't use $this, is because the closure is an object in the background (the Closure class).

There are two ways around this.  First, is add the __invoke method (What's called if you call $obj())..

```
class Dog {

    public function __invoke($method) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        array_shift($args); //get rid of the method name
        if (is_callable(array($this, $method))) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $args);
        } else {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('Unknown method: '.$method);
        }
    }

    public function greet($greeting) {
        $self = $this;
        return function() use ($greeting, $self) {
            $self('do_greet', $greeting);
        };
    }

    protected function do_greet($greeting) {
        echo "$greeting, I am a {$this->_color} dog named {$this->_name}.";
    }
}
```

If you want the closure to not change if you modify the host object, you can just change the return function to something like:

```
public function greet($greeting) {
    $self = (clone) $this;
    return function() use ($greeting, $self) {
        $self('do_greet', $greeting);
    };
}
```

The other option, is to provide a generic getter:

```
class Dog {

    public function __get($name) {
        return isset($this->$name) ? $this->$name : null;
    }

}
```

For more information, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: I'd add you can make the field accessible through reflection.

Comment: You can use `$this` in closures as of PHP 5.4

Comment: This is an old answer I know. But it's worth noting that Closure::bind() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) is also a viable solution here.

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 5.4.0 Alpha1, you can access `$this` from within the context of an object instance:

```
<?php
class Dog
{
  private $_name;
  protected $_color;

  public function __construct($name, $color)
  {
    $this->_name = $name;
    $this->_color = $color;
  }

  public function greet($greeting)
  {
    $func = function() use ($greeting) {
      echo "$greeting, I am a {$this->_color} dog named {$this->_name}.";
    };

    $func();
  }
}

$dog = new Dog("Rover","red");
$dog->greet("Hello");
```

You can also do this:

```
$dog = new Dog("Rover", "red");
$getname = Closure::bind($dog, function() { return $this->_name; });
echo $getname(); // Rover
```

As you can see, it's possible to easily mess with private data... so be careful.

Answer (score 3):

Well it makes sense that you cannot access private and protected fields of an object. And by explicitly passing `$self` to your function, it is treated just as a normal object.
You should create getters in order to access these values , i.e. :

```
class Dog
{
    private $_name;
    protected $_color;

    public function __construct($name, $color)
    {
         $this->_name = $name;
        $this->_color = $color;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $this->_name;
    }
    public function getColor() {
        return $this->_color;
    }
    public function greet($greeting)
    {
         $self = $this;
         return function() use ($greeting, $self) {
             echo "$greeting, I am a {$self->getColor()} dog named {$self->getName()}.";
         };
    }
}
```

You should create getter (and setters) anyway, for matter of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)).

---

Another note: The article you link to was published before the final version of PHP 5.3 was released. Maybe this implicit object passing was removed.

Comment: Yes I know it's not like the current version.

That I want is to create a new function of the class Dog and then in the function I can access to $this without to pass $self.

Comment: You say "You should create getter (and setters) anyway, for matter of encapsulation." I disagree. Encapsulation is, as mentioned in the article you linked, about restricting direct access to an object's internal state. If you provide getters and setters for private attributes you are _breaking_ encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

I use this create_closure() in my work to seperate callbacks into Classes:

```
<?php
function create_closure($fun, $args, $uses)
         {$params=explode(',', trim($args.','.$uses, ','));
          $str_params='';
          foreach ($params as $v)
                  {$v=trim($v, ' &$');
                   $str_params.='\''.$v.'\'=>&$'.$v.', ';
                  }
          return "return function({$args}) use ({$uses}) {{$fun}(array({$str_params}));};";
         }
?>
```

example:

```
<?php
$loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, eval(create_closure('pop_message', '$timer', '$cache_key, $n, &$response, &$redis_client')));

function pop_message($params)
         {extract($params, EXTR_REFS);
          $redis_client->ZRANGE($cache_key, 0, $n)
                            ->then(//normal
                                   function($data) use ($cache_key, $n, &$timer, &$response, &$redis_client)
                                   {//...
                                   },
                                   //exception
                                   function ($e) use (&$timer, &$response, &$redis_client)
                                   {//...
                                   }
                                  );
         }
?>
```