# Laravel: Pass classfunction as callback in eager load?

Tags: php, laravel

I use [constraint eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) with an anonymous function:

```
$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}])->get();
```

Now I want to replace the anonymous function with a class function. According to [PHP: How to use a class function as a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954168/php-how-to-use-a-class-function-as-a-callback) I found

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an
>   object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

Thus I expected that the following will work:

```
public function start()
{
   $users = App\User::with(['posts' => [$this, 'addRestrain']])->get();
   // ...
}

private function addRestrain($query)
{
  $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}
```

However, Laravel detects that the passed parameter is not a closure, but an array:

> "Type error: Argument 3 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::eagerLoadRelation() must be an
>   instance of Closure, array given, called in

Does that mean that it is not possible to use a class function for the eager load constraint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from PHP 7.1.0, you can use `Closure::fromCallable` ([**docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php)):

```
$users = App\User::with(
  [ 'posts' => \Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'addRestrain']) ]
)->get();
```

Otherwise, you're limited to using anonymous function wrapping `$this->addRestrain` call instead.

Comment: Thats awesome, thank you! But `$this->addRestrain` wont work in Laravel I guess, I get then an `Undefined property` error.

Comment: Do you do it correctly, like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881311/define-a-closure-as-method-from-class)? And which version of PHP is used?